# customize UIPageControl dots

Tags: swift, xcode, draw, uipagecontrol

I'm currently trying to customize the UIPageControl so it will fit my needs. However I seem to be having a problem when implementing some logic in the `draw`

What I want to do is to be able to user `IBInspectable` variables to draw out the `UIPageControl` however those seem to still be `nil` when the `draw` method is being called and when I try to implement my logic in the `awakeFromNib` for instance it won't work.

What I did so far is the following

```
class BoardingPager: UIPageControl {
    @IBInspectable var size: CGSize!
    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor!
    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat! = 1

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        setDots()
    }

    func setDots() {
        for i in (0..<self.numberOfPages) {
            let dot = self.subviews[i]
            if size != nil {
                let dotFrame = CGRect(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2, width: size.width, height: size.height)
                dot.frame = dotFrame
            }

            if i != self.currentPage {
                dot.layer.cornerRadius = dot.frame.size.height / 2
                dot.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
                dot.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Another problem I'm facing is that I want to remove/add a border when the current page changes.

I'm hoping someone will be able to help me out

Comment: I think you should split this into separate questions, it would be easier to get answers.