# Make a custom UIControl with IBDesignable & IBInspectable

Tags: swift, uipagecontrol, uicontrol

I'm currently trying to make my own version of a `PageControl` much like `UIPageControl`. However I've never done something like this and I'm stuck on how to continue/what I should do to make certain things actually work.

What I want to do is make it possible to change certain things regarding the dots inside the `PageControl` by using the `interface builder` however I'm not sure how to do this.

I followed [this](http://www.appdesignvault.com/custom-segmented-control-swift-tutorial/) tutorial and then started changing stuff so it would be tailored to my desires however it doesn't work (obviously I guess)

This is what my class looks like right now

```
@IBDesignable
class BoardingPageControl: UIControl {

    @IBInspectable var dotSize: CGFloat! = 7 { didSet { setupView() } }
    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat! = 0 { didSet { setupView() } }
    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor! = UIColor.clear { didSet { setupView() } }
    @IBInspectable var dotCount: Int! = 3 { didSet { setupView() } }
    @IBInspectable var dotColor: UIColor! = UIColor.blue { didSet { setupView() } }
    @IBInspectable var dotSelectedColor: UIColor! = UIColor.black { didSet { setupView() } }
    @IBInspectable var dotSelectedBorder: Bool! = false { didSet { setupView() } }

    let DOT_PADDING = 10
    var selectedView = UIView()

    var dots = [UIView]() {
        didSet {
            setupDots()
        }
    }

    var selectedDot: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            displayNewSelectedIndex()
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }

    func setupView() {
        let frameWidth = (dotSize * CGFloat(dotCount)) + CGFloat((DOT_PADDING * dotCount))
        self.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.minX, y: self.frame.minY,
                            width: frameWidth, height: dotSize)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        setupDots()
    }

    func setupDots() {
        for dot in dots {
            dot.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        dots.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)

        for index in 0...dotCount {
            let dot = UIView()
            dot.layer.cornerRadius = dotSize / 2
            dot.clipsToBounds = true

            let x = CGFloat(CGFloat(index) * dotSize + CGFloat(index * DOT_PADDING))
            dot.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: 0, width: dotSize, height: dotSize)

            dot.backgroundColor = dotColor
            dot.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
            dot.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
            dot.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)

            self.addSubview(dot)
            dots.append(dot)
        }
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        selectedView.backgroundColor = dotSelectedColor
        selectedView.layer.cornerRadius = selectedView.frame.height / 2

        if !dotSelectedBorder {
            selectedView.layer.borderWidth = 0
        }
        for index in 0...dots.count - 1 {
            var dot = dots[index]

            dot = selectedView
        }
    }

    func displayNewSelectedIndex() {
        let dot = dots[selectedDot]
        self.selectedView.frame = dot.frame
    }

}
```

The values that are being entered at the `interface builder` aren't taken into consideration at this moment (possibly trying to use them before they are set?) while they should be since they are important.

I hope someone can help me out/guide me on how to do this exactly.

Comment: Either you are subclassing too high or not. Those "dots" as part of what you get when you subclass *UIPageControl*. So, why are you subclassing *UIControl*? Me thinks you are trying to "reinvent the wheel"! :-)

Comment: @dfd Because you can't change the actual dots of the UIPageControl without looping through the subview which is (as far as I know) considered as hacky/bad practice. I did try to do that earlier today tho http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42783598/customize-uipagecontrol-dots